# FreeSWITCH simple configuration for audio call between two computers

Tags: voip, sip

I have two computers and I want to make audio calls between them. Each one of them is behind a different NAT.

I am an absolute beginner and I have no idea what I need to configure. After reading and asking some friends I decided to use SIP and FreeSWITCH as a proxy. I want a simple configuration that will allow to make audio calls between the computers.

I installed FreeSWITCH on a Debian system and I'm trying to configure it. I created two users and other than that, I use the default configuration. From two different client systems (one Ekiga and one Linphone) I am able to register to FreeSWITCH.

When I try to call from one client to the other, I get an error "User is temporarily unavailable".

It looks like I have to configure something else in FreeSWITCH so that the two clients can see each other. Unfortunately I have no idea what and it seems like I have to read a ton of documentation to find out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We  need to disable the firewall for particular ports:

```
◦   sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public –add-port=5060/udp --permanent
◦   sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5080/udp --permanent
◦   sudo firewall-cmd --reload
◦   sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```